# Value of variable becomes undefined after calling data service

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-controller

I have a angular js controller 'TakeSurveyController' which calls a data service 'takeSurveyDataService'. The controller has a variable empId which I am accessing successfully using the 'this' keyword. However, the value of this variable becomes undefined soon after I make a call to the data service.

```
(function(){
dataUrls = {

    employeeUrl : '/SurveyPortal/Company/Employees/'    
}

angular.module('takeSurvey',[])
.service('takeSurveyDataService',function($http,$log){
    this.checkEmployee = function(employeeId){
        var url = dataUrls.employeeUrl + employeeId;
        return $http.get(url);
    };

})
.controller('TakeSurveyController',function($http,takeSurveyDataService,$location){
    this.empId = '';
    this.checkEmployee = function(){
        takeSurveyDataService.checkEmployee(this.empId).then(this.attemptSurvey);//empId has value here. Call successful to data service
    };
    this.attemptSurvey = function(employeeResponse) {
        if(employeeResponse.data=="true"){
            $location.path('/attemptSurvey/'+this.empId); //empId variable undefined here, unable to access value that was available above

        }
        else{
            this.empId = '';
            alert("This empId has not been registered. Please register before taking survey!");
        }

    };
})
})();
```

Following is the html code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<div align="center" style="margin-top:50px">
    <form name="checkEmployee" ng-controller="TakeSurveyController as takeSurveyController" ng-submit="takeSurveyController.checkEmployee()" >
        <input type="text" ng-model="takeSurveyController.empId" placeholder="Employee ID" /><br>
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-large btn-success" value="Move to survey" />
    </form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Where are you initializing `this.empId`? I don't see any code setting value for `this.empId` above except the last else condition

Comment: I had removed by mistake while trying to fix the issue. Added it again.

Comment: Still it's not clear. Initially you're setting `this.empId=''` And  in `this.attemptSurvey` you're trying to access it. So it will be `''` Nowhere you're setting value to it.

Comment: the form submit will cause the empId to have the value entered by the user. Do you want me to add the html code also?

Comment: Yes, that would be great

Comment: Do you actually need `empId` for binding in a view? If not, it might be easier to just declare it as a variable in the controller and not worry about the intricacies of `this` in various contexts, which I think is the problem here.

Comment: I didn't get you Jens as I am a bit new to angular. How else can I get the value of empId if I don't use this?

Comment: When the promise calls the attemptSurvey callback function, the function is not bound to the controller anymore. So `this`, in that context, is not the controller anymore. `this` handling is awful in JavaScript, and using `this`causes an enormous amount of bugs like the one you're having. I would suggest avoiding `this`, avoiding the `controllerAs` feature, and use the scope instead to provide values and functions to the view.

Comment: Thanks, I got what u mean!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must be very carefull using this inside functions since 'this' words get different meaning each time depending on context. I believe during promise callback 'this' get's different meaning and it is loosing connection with TakeSurveyController. Please try to assign 'this' to 'self' variable which is always good practice in angular and js:

```
(function(){
dataUrls = {

    employeeUrl : '/SurveyPortal/Company/Employees/'    
}

angular.module('takeSurvey',[])
.service('takeSurveyDataService',function($http,$log){
    var self = this;
    self.checkEmployee = function(employeeId){
        var url = dataUrls.employeeUrl + employeeId;
        return $http.get(url);
    };

})
.controller('TakeSurveyController',function($http,takeSurveyDataService,$location){
    var self = this;
    self.empId = '';
    self.checkEmployee = function(){
        takeSurveyDataService.checkEmployee(self.empId).then(self.attemptSurvey);//empId has value here. Call successful to data service
    };
    self.attemptSurvey = function(employeeResponse) {
        if(employeeResponse.data=="true"){
            $location.path('/attemptSurvey/'+self.empId); //empId variable undefined here, unable to access value that was available above

        }
        else{
            self.empId = '';
            alert("This empId has not been registered. Please register before taking survey!");
        }

    };
})
})();
```