# shared service returns variable as undefined angularjs

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-core-mvc

I am trying to share a variable between two controllers using a service.
below is my code:

```
(function() {
'use strict';

angular.module('simple.module')
    .service("projectService",
        function($http, $httpParamSerializerJQLike) {
            var projectId;
            //var service = {};
            //return {
            this.getProjects = function() {
                return $http.get("/project/getprojects");
            };
            this.favourites = function(id) {
                return $http({
                    method: "POST",
                    url: "/project/markasfavourite",
                    headers: { 'Content-Type': "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" },
                    data: id
                });
            };
            this.setProjectId = function(id) {
                projectId = id;
            };
            this.getProjectId = function() {
                return projectId; <----this is returned as undefined
            };
           // return service;
            // };
        });})();
```

I am new to angular, and have already put in a lot of time to get this to work. Initially i was using a factory, later switched to service and did a lot of looking around from:
[Why does this AngularJs Service with variable object name return an undefined object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32627017/why-does-this-angularjs-service-with-variable-object-name-return-an-undefined-ob)
[Value of variable becomes undefined after calling data service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29728152/value-of-variable-becomes-undefined-after-calling-data-service)
[Variable undefined in Service, after saving a value in it (AngularJS)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32112914/variable-undefined-in-service-after-saving-a-value-in-it-angularjs)
and many other places, so before this question gets marked as duplicate and closed down, please could someone point out what am i missing? why is projectId always returned as undefined?
Thank you.

Edit:controllers

```
 function projectsController(projectService, $window) {
    var vm = this;vm.edit = function (id) {
        projectService.setProjectId(id);
        $window.location.pathname = '/project/create/'+id;
    };}
function createController(createService,projectService, $window) { 
    var vm = this;
    debugger;
    var projectId = projectService.getProjectId();}
```

Comment: are you able to set the `projectId` ?

Comment: Your code seems to be working just fine for me: https://plnkr.co/edit/fKO6dn06DQfj3PKXgCA4?p=preview

Comment: @Searching, yes in one controller(projectController), its being set like so  vm.edit = function (id) {
            projectService.setProjectId(id);
            //$window.location.pathname = '/project/create/'+id;
        };

Comment: @BenBeck ,thats strange then maybe there is a problem in the way i am accessing it, will edit the code.

Comment: @smons I'd double check your variable is actually being set.

Comment: @BenBeck thanks, the plunk you created does show that the id is being set and is accessible in both the controllers, however i can't seem to get it going :(